# Plot Black Body Radiation

Tags: plotting, physics

This is the version of Planck's Equation I am unable to Plot:

```
L[λ_]:=((8.0*π*2.9979x10^8*2.9979*10^8*6.626*10^-34)/\
λ^5)*(1.0/((E^((2.9979*10^8*6.626*10^-34)/(1.3806*10^-34*\
λ*5000.0)) )-1.0))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used every version of Planck's constant, Boltzmann's constant and the speed of light I can find on the internet. Nothing works. My formula is identical to that used by Zach Heuman in his manipulate demonstration.

Comment: Replace `x` with `*` and you're all set.

Comment: Replacing x with * yields: 1.49667*10^-15/((-1. + E^(287760./\[Lambda])) \[Lambda]^5) Unfortunately, still no Plot. What should I use for values on the X and Y axis?

Comment: For PlotRange-> I tried {{0,2.0*10^-6},{0, 1.1*10^14}} All I got was a flat line at the bottom of the Plot. No bell curve.

Comment: You may have the wrong exponent on your value for $k_B$.  Evaluate `UnitConvert@Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"] // N` to see the value in SI units.  Your values of $c$ and $h$ are already in SI units, so use meters for $\lambda$.  The final units will be in watts per cubic meter, or watts per square meter of surface area per meter of wavelength, which may be confirmed by evaluating `Quantity["PlanckConstant"] Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]^2/
     Quantity["Meters"]^5/Quantity["Watts"] // UnitConvert // QuantityUnit`

Answer (score 7):

Color curves by the peak wavelength:

```
PlanckPlot[wen_] := 
 PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[wen, "Kelvins"], 
   "SpectralPlot"] /. {ColorData[97, 1] -> 
    PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[wen, "Kelvins"], "Color"]}
Show[PlanckPlot /@ {6000, 5778, 5500, 5000, 4500, 4000, 3500}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3*10^(-6)}, All}, ImageSize -> 350, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Wavelenght(m)", 
   "Spectral energy density(kJ/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \
\(3\)]\))"}]
```

[image]

Color along the curves according to the wavelength:

```
PlanckPlot[wen_] := 
 PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[wen, "Kelvins"], 
   "SpectralPlot"] /. {ColorData[97, 1] -> 
    PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[wen, "Kelvins"], "Color"]}
ColorPlanckPlot[wen_] := 
 ListLinePlot[
  First[Cases[PlanckPlot[wen], 
    Line[a_] :> Map[Apply[{#*10^9, #2} &], a], Infinity]], 
  ColorFunction -> (PlanckRadiationLaw[
      Quantity[1, "WienWavelengthDisplacementLawConstant"]/
       Quantity[#/10^9, "Meters"], "Color"] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
Show[ColorPlanckPlot /@ {6000, 5778, 5500, 5000, 4500, 4000, 3500}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2000}, All}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Wavelenght(nm)", 
   "Spectral energy density(kJ/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \
\(3\)]\))"}, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using builtin functionalities and SI units:

```
h = Quantity["PlanckConstant"] // UnitConvert // QuantityMagnitude
(*    132521403/200000000000000000000000000000000000000000    *)

c = Quantity["SpeedOfLight"] // UnitConvert // QuantityMagnitude
(*    299792458    *)

kB = Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"] // UnitConvert // QuantityMagnitude
(*    1380649/100000000000000000000000000000    *)

With[{T = 5000},
  Plot[(2 h c^2)/λ^5 1/(E^((h c)/(λ kB T)) - 1), {λ, 0, 5000*10^-9}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"λ [m]", "flux [W/m^3]"}]]
```

[image]

You can see that this matches the built-in plot you get with

```
PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[5000, "Kelvins"], "SpectralPlot"]
```